# How can I use zmq (using python) to send HTTP messages

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

I want to create a URL which can be used to send HTTP messages. It'll allow an application to send HTTP messages then I can extract relevant information from that HTTP message and display it over a webpage.

Basically I want to create a URL, my application will be hitting that URL and sending HTTP messages.

I thought to use :

1. pyzmq (to enable communication)
2. Django (to create a UI and a URL where application will be sending the message to)

Then I can display the information on the UI for all the messages received.

Can someone please advise me on the zmq part, I can't think of the correct method to use  in this case.

Comment: where is your attempt, please?

Comment: You could expose an endpoint with Django/Flask receiving a json message, and from this backend HTTP server sending messages to ZeroMQ socket. 
The mode of operation (whether Send, Publish, etc., and if the HTTP server works sync/asyncronously) depends entirely on the requierements of your application.